# IntlDateFormatter always en_US output for month/day names

Tags: php, locale, intl

I'm trying to implement locale support using the Intl package. The `NumberFormatter` works and changes the output style when the `Locale` is changed, but `IntlDateFormatter` does not seem to detect the locale change.

I'm setting the locale using this piece of code, switching between "en_US" and "sv_SV".

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale . ".UTF-8");
return \Locale::setDefault($locale);
```

And then initializing the `IntlDateFormatter` using this code

```
// _locale is set on each pass, since locale may change during runtime
$this->_locale = \Locale::getDefault(); // en_US or sv_SV
$this->_dateFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter($this->_locale, null, null);
```

When I now try to format a day name, e.g Wednesday, I always get the English representation of the name - even when the Swedish representation is expected.

```
$this->_dateFormatter->setPattern("EEEE");
return mb_convert_case($this->_dateFormatter->format($this->getDateTime($argument)), MB_CASE_LOWER);
```

This should output "onsdag", but "wednesday" is outputed for the both locales.
What am I doing wrong here?